# SOAP request in JMeter - Error reading XMLStreamReader: Unexpected EOF in prolog

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, jmeter

I use same request in `JMeter` as in `SoapUI`. It is working in `SoapUI`, but gives error in `JMeter`.

> soap:ClientError
>   reading XMLStreamReader: Unexpected EOF in prolog  at [row,col
>   {unknown-source}]:
>   [1,0]

Comment: I your payload (XML message) is the same and the results are different, you need to compare the HTTP headers as well. The compression, HTTP chunking and other parameters might matter, especially if the target system uses an older HTTP server.

Comment: @KarelHusa : Thanks, `Content-Type: text/xml` solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTTP Header Manager` needed to execute `SOAP` requests.

```
Content-Type: text/xml
```

Answer (score 1):

If your request works in SoapUI you can record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The fastest way is using [JMeter's "Templates" Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)

   - From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
     [image: JMeter Recording Template]
   - Expand `Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start"
2. Prepare SoapUI for recording

   - From SoapUI Main Menu choose `File -> Preferences -> Proxy Settings` and click "Manual"
   - Use `localhost` as "Host" and `8888` as Port

     [image: SoapUI recording]
3. Run your request in SoapUI
4. JMeter will capture the request and save the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler under `Test Plan -> Thread Group -> Recording Controller`. You should be able to replay the request in JMeter after that.